# Can't import XLSX files into Magento

Tags: excel, magento, import, xlsx

I've got an XLSX file, filled with zip codes - almost 3000. I can't seem to find a way to import the file, and I really don't want to type in every single zipcodes manually. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Where are you trying to import them to?

Comment: This is one of those Magento admin questions that belong over on magento.stackexchange.